# In Islam, do double standards apply to women in regards to sex?

Tags: sex, men-women

Humans in general everywhere let men have sex casually but if a woman does it, it is frowned because of double standards.

*Question*: In Islam, do double standards apply to women in regards to sex?

Gender-based double standards occurs outside of Islam.  For example, the word "slut" in the English dictionary is a woman doing what men do just because she doesn't have the body. *A woman with the sexual morals of a man.*

I cannot ask Muslims face to face and I do not know how to apply the Qur'an in real life?

Comment: What do you mean by "favor men over women when it comes to sex"? Are you talking about sex outside of marriage? Please clarify what you are asking about. Thank you!

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I mean. Like, many Muslim boys I have seen are dating. But in general, forget what Muslims do. Many christians, French people have mistresses, go to prostitutes. And if a woman lets say does it once, she is deemed as a slut. A man in America for example can get away. Because I think you can tell if a woman is a virfin or not by her body even if she is lying, right? But a man can lie and get away, I think. Sorry.

Comment: You know how humans give double standards and favor men in general whether scottish or indian, danish ,etc. Forget what humans do but what about Allah? Does he get angry when a man can get away with casual sex? And, does Allah get angry at those who praises men who are studs, playboys, womanizers etc? Thank you.

Comment: In Islam, if a man and a woman commit adultery, they are both called Zani (adulterer) and Zaniyah (adulteress), even if they did it once. Is that the equality you are asking about?

Comment: Well, sort of. But how come outside of marriage it is okay for unmarried boys to date and have sex?

Comment: **It is not at all OK *for unmarried boys to date and have sex?*** Would my statement suffice in convincing you or do you need references?

Comment: @user15732 Sex outside marriage is prohibited in Islam. Muslims are allowed to have sex only with their spouse(s) or what their right hand possess. The muslims boys/girls you see dating or doing other things are going against Islam. We should pray for them and guard ourselves too from such unIslamic behaviour. Salam!

Answer (score 3):

### All perfect praise be to Allah.

When it comes to the issue you are raising, you are calling it HAVING SEX OCCASIONALLY, but i suspect by the word slut and what i can sense in your question is about prostitution, and why only women are called sluts, while men are also involved in it.
**Islam has same ruling for both men and women involved in illegal sexual activities**, islam does not differentiate them in any matter like this.
 Islam does differentiate where necessary, like women have leave from prayer in their periods, while men have no leave at all in prayer. And many other things.

### Allah knows best

Comment: Thank you brother? I do not know Arabic. I do not know if you are a man or not. You write simple and straightforward. I think your a man. I like how you answer most questions. Thanks.

Comment: Well i don't think it matters a lot if i am male or female, but as of my name people can guess i am male. And thank-you for appreciation, I try to answer as good and precisely as i can. Correct me anywhere i seem wrong. Jazakallah. And also, if this answers the question, mark this as an answer. Jazakallah.